# Formatting Flask app logs in json

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I'm working with a Python/Flask application and trying to get the logs to be formatted (by line) in json.

Using the python-json-logger package, I've modified the formatter for the app.logger as follows:

```
from pythonjsonlogger import jsonlogger
formatter = jsonlogger.JsonFormatter(
    '%(asctime) %(levelname) %(module) %(funcName) %(lineno) %(message)')
app.logger.handlers[0].setFormatter(formatter)
```

This works as expected. Any messages passed to `app.logger` are correctly formatted in json.

However the application is also automatically logging all requests. This information shows up in stdout as follows:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Jun/2015 12:22:03] "GET /portal/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

I want this information to be formatted in json as well. I've been looking for the logger/code that is responsible for creating this output with no success.

Where is this output generated?
Are the mechanisms to change the formatting of this logged information?

Comment: Those logs you're seeing are probably coming from the web server you're utilizing and not from your `wsgi` app. Which server are you using?

Comment: @MartijnPieters you might be right but it wouldn't make sense for `Flask` to log access requests as it's not supposed to be its job

Comment: @sirfz: except, it doesn't. You are in fact correct.

Answer (score 8):

When you use the `app.logger` attribute for the first time, Flask sets up some log handlers:

- a debug logger that is set to log level `DEBUG` and that filters on `app.debug` being true.
- a production logger that is set to `ERROR`.

You can remove those handlers again yourself, by running:

```
app.logger.handlers[:] = []
```

However, the log line you see is not logged by Flask, but by the WSGI server. Both the built-in Werkzeug server (used when you use `app.run()`) and various other WSGI servers do this. Gunicorn for example uses the default Python logger to record access.

The built-in WSGI server should never be used in production (it won't scale well, and is not battle-hardened against malicious attackers).

For Gunicorn, you can disable *log propagation* to keep the logging separate:

```
logging.getLogger('gunicorn').propagate = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Flask internally uses `werkzeug server`. Those logs are printed by it, not flask. You can access to werkzeug logger with `logging.getLogger('werkzeug')` and configure as you wish. For example:

```
werkzeug = logging.getLogger('werkzeug')
if len(werkzeug.handlers) == 1:
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(message)s', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    werkzeug.handlers[0].setFormatter(formatter)
```